# Add Equations or Math Mode in a PowerPoint Slide Using R officer Package

Tags: officer

I am using officer to create PowerPoint presentations. I have been able to add figures, tables, and images to slides. Now I would like to add equations.

In the past, I have used LaTeX via Sweave to do this. However, this is a corporate presentation and it must be in PowerPoint and it must meet certain template requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no function for that in officer.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but thanks a lot for the response.